# How to crawl publicly shared Secret (secret.ly) posts

Tags: web-scraping, web-crawler

Secret ([secret.ly](http://secret.ly)) is an anonymous social network where people share their thoughts in the form of short messages. From time to time people share their "secrets" on social media like [this](https://www.secret.ly/p/ynwmmkfzxtzscyxipcslwelxtt), [this](https://www.secret.ly/p/sclntscowhhovyrdmklwhnvynn) and [this](https://www.secret.ly/p/dldckvtykombjnfyiprfvgrbii)
I am trying to create a stream of publicly available secrets and I was wondering if there is a way to crawl the secret.ly domain to extract all those public secrets despite the fact that the url's are random strings. I could just search on Twitter but I am wondering if there is a way to just do it directly on [secret.ly](http://secret.ly)

Comment: This smells much like a "please do my work for me" -- finding a way to index those URLs is really the core of the product/service you're trying to create, after all.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a start using perl. It appears they are also linked in social media. This script will only get the site and dump the links. I couldn't do much more without knowing more of what you want.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use WWW::Mechanize;

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();

$mech->get('http://www.secret.ly');
print $mech->dump_links;
```

**Update:** There is also a [find_all_links](http://search.cpan.org/~ether/WWW-Mechanize-1.73/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm#$mech-%3Efind_all_links%28_..._%29) method of WWW::Mechanize which you may find helpful, too.